# Converting databricks sql code to pyspark/python using classes and function

Tags: python, sql, class, pyspark, databricks

```
    with part1 as
    (
    Select d.*
    ,h.HospitalName_comb COMPARATOR_HOSPITAL
    from myvdi hospital_list_1_flag f left join myvdi.hospital_Efficiency d
    on f. HOSPITAL_PRACTICE_NO = d. HOSPITAL_ PRACTICE NO
    left join mydi hospital distance_ Dev h
    on h. HospitalName = d. HOSPITAL_ PRACTICE_NO
    and h.HospitalName_comb <> d.HOSPITAL_PRACTICE_NO
    and trim(h.StateName_comb) = d. PROVINCE_DESCR
    and h.Distance <= 15 where 1=1
    and f.Keep_flag = 0
    )

    Select d.*,
    d1.EVENTS COMPARATOR_EVENTS
    , d1.CAPABILITY COMAPRATOR_CAPABILITY
    ,d1.HOSPITAL EFFICIENCY COMPARATOR_EFFICIENCY 
    ,d1.CPE_CMA HOSPITAL COMPARATOR_CPE_CMA
    ,d1. EVENTS/cast (sum(d1.EVENTS) over (partition by d.HOSPITAL PRACTICE_NO) as float)        COMARRATOR_MARKET_SHARE ,d1.EVENTS/cast(sum(d1.EVENTS) over (partition by d.HOSPITAL_  PRACTICE_NO) as float)*
(d. HOSPITAL_COST WEIGHT) *
d.CPE_CMA_HOSPITAL - d1.CPE_CMA_HOSPITAL) SAVINGS
    from part1 d
    Join myvdi.hospital_list_1_flag f
    on d. COMPARATOR HOSPITAL = F.HOSPITAL PRACTICE NO
    and f.Keep_ flag = 1
    Left join myvdi.hospital_Efficiency d1
    on d1.HOSPITAL PRACTICE_NO = d. COMPARATOR HOSPITAL
```

I have done all this in sql but now i want to structure and optimize the code with the help of classes, function and objects. Which classes ,functions and object should i create . Write a dummy pyspark/python code. You can Use init and transform function

A pyspark/Python code

Comment: Last few lines are also a part of the main code.

Comment: I think if you just formatted your query better you might be all set. It's not very complex. There are cases where the pyspark dialect is really the tool for the job, but it all turns in to the same instructions. It's a common misconception that the pyspark dialect is faster than spark sql.

Comment: @Diksha Are you using Azure databricks?